# Quotation Marks: One or two sets of quotation marks around a quotation consisting of an incomplete sentence followed by a complete sentence

Tags: quotation-marks

I know that one set of quotation marks around a quotation consisting of two complete sentences is correct. Do you still use one set of quotation marks if the quotation begins in the middle of the first sentence or should there be one set of quotation marks around the partial sentence and another set around the complete sentence that follows?

An Example: The young man looked into the young woman's eyes and said: "we are in this together." "Let's look out for one another." Or is better to omit the quotation marks after together and before Let's?

Comment: For best results, you should add an example passage to your question.

Comment: (A) If you use 2 sets , it looks like the young man said something & the young woman replied. (B) If you use 1 set , it means the young man said both. (3) If the Initial sentence is Partial , use "... words here. Next sentence is here" (4) If the last sentence is Partial , use "This is the X. The Y is ...." (E) In general , we use 1 set for 1 speaker !

Comment: That is dialogue.

Comment: I am persuaded to use just the one set of quotation marks for the reason given. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If both sentences are said by the same person, use only one set of quotation marks.

"We are in this together" looks like a complete sentence to me, but even if it were not, I don't know why you think it needs to be enclosed in separate quotes. It would just confuse the reader as to who is speaking.